# HtmlHelper class in web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a Web API, we have created a `HtmlHelper` class.

My first question is, can we use `HtmlHelper` class in the controller part? Because I came to know that helper classes are basically used in the design page (view and not in controller)

In that helper class, I see declarations that look like:

```
public static string GetCountryDomain(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Area area)
{
    //body
}
```

In my controller I want to call above method from the `HtmlHelper` class. It expects 2 parameters.

```
HtmlHelper.GetCountryDomain(area_id);
```

Can someone explain what first parameter I need to pass in order to call above method of `HtmlHelper` class?

Comment: You could use your HtmlHelper in your controller, but in my opinion you shouldn't. Like you said, HtmlHelper are normally part of a view and render some HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension method. The first parameter is the `instance` itself. So `HtmlHelper` is the first parameter and is automatically passed in it as `htmlHelper`. You just have to supply the other parameters only. You can read more from here -

[Extension Methods (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx)